# SQLite Finding all documents containing a word

Tags: sql, sqlite, set

I have a SQLite database that has a table for documents, a table for unique words (stemmed and stripped of common words) and a table that indicates which words are used in which documents:

```
CREATE TABLE Docs ( DocId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, DocName TEXT )
CREATE TABLE Words ( WordId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Word TEXT )
CREATE TABLE WordsInDoc ( WordsInDocId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                          DocId INT REFERENCES Docs(DocId),
                          WordId INT REFERENCES Words(WordId)
                        )
```

I am trying to write a query that takes a list of words (conditioned as above) and returns the DocIds of all docs that contains all the words.

It feels like something that I should be able to use the set operations of SQLite to do, but I can't quite get my brain around the SQL. I can of course do it in the application layer, but it doesn't seem like the right design.

Can anybody recommend the right approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for documents that contain *some* of these words, then count how many words occur for each document:

```
SELECT DocId
FROM WordsInDoc
WHERE WordId IN (17, 23, 37, 42, 69, 105, 666)
GROUP BY DocId
HAVING COUNT(*) = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select D.docID, D.docName from Docs D join wordsInDoc WID on
D.docID = WID.docID
inner join WORDS w
on w.wordId = wid.wordID
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e6859/3)** here..

Comment: I'm confused, that just joins all the tables together, but I want to select the docs that have ALL the words, not a query that lists every word for every document. What is the where clause that identifies all the DocId of all the Docs that contain the words "Stack" and "Overflow" and "is" and "helpful". BTW I had never heard of SQLfiddle -- very cool.